# Dragonslayers: Accounting For Draconic Culture

Tags: society, magic, medieval

Dragonslayers are a common trope in fantasy, but mine are a bit different (please see [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/196004/balancing-bloodstones) and [that](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195379/unconventional-rebirth-is-it-checked) for more on that). The problem is not with the dragonslayers but with the dragons themselves.

**Background:**
Yes, this is relevant, sorry it's so long. Long ago, there were only two dragons, Curse and Regis. Curse was the first Dark Dragon, and the first male; and Regis was the first Light dragon (and the first female). The two did *not* mate; for while Regis chose the way of peace, order, and virtue, Curse chose the way of violence, chaos, and evil.

These dragons soon came to two powerful magical constructs (formed of warped reality, or discord, which is the driving force behind magic): the Source Crystal and Neosis Gem. The Neosis Gem was a giant diamond capable of generating and harnessing creative energy (AKA creating more dragons), while the Source Stone was a giant stone that would channel the Neosis energies, making each dragon created by the Gem reflect its creator and yet be genetically unique.

To make a long story shorter, a third being, as powerful as Curse and Regis, also sought the Gem and Stone and when it couldn't have them it went kamikaze and killed not only the two (battling) dragons but itself as well. The subsequent release of magical essence inadvertently melded and went into both artifacts, and thus the dragons were born.

Each dragon reflected their harsh origins; since Curse and Regis were both forceful creatures and felt the need to fight for their beliefs (and to prove their dominance; they're *dragons* after all), so do their spawn. Because of this, the early dragons were very warlike creatures, and their world became a war zone. This belligerence was inherited by modern dragons, along with their ancestor's courtship rituals.

Since dragons prized power and fighting prowess, it didn't take long for dragons to unanimously decide that one's would-be mate would have to prove him- or her-self by defeating (read: subduing, overpowering) them. This led to dragons seeking powerful/skilled mates since no one wanted a weak mate; no, no, the thinking went; the harder the fight required to earn the right to mate with someone, the better they'll be as a mate!
This wouldn't really be a problem, but due to in-story reasons, all dragons are A) capable of becoming human and B) all learn they can become human from the moment puberty starts unless already informed.

**The Problem:**
Since dragonslayers are elite warriors who are employed for the sole purpose of subduing, overpowering or slaying dragons, they will (almost) inadvertently become attractive under the dragon's courtship rules. Sure, sensible dragons will stay away, but most dragons *aren't* sensible-natural selection favored those crazy enough to take on powerful members of the opposite gender, those who'd be difficult and even dangerous to court, and modern dragons reflect that.

Modern dragons have also inherited a martial code, which leads them to respect those who can rival or exceed their own level of power or skill, which only worsens the problem. "But wait," you say. "Is this really a problem?" YES.

1. Most Dragonslayers are Male
   Due to this being (somewhat) realistic medieval fantasy, sexist attitudes and cultural expectations make men naturally more like to be dragonslayers. Being a dragonslayer also requires a certain amount of recklessness (AKA guts, courage), which I know from personal experience men are more likely to have. And men aren't exactly known for rejecting women's advances, in *any* era.
2. Veteran Dragonslayers *Aren't* Idiots
   This is pretty much self-explanatory; in order to become a veteran dragonslayer, a "pro" if you will, one needs to have a certain amount of brains, common sense, foresight, and critical thinking ability. Accepting a dragon's advances comes with a lot of benefits, while rejecting them comes with very few benefits;
3. Having children with a dragon results in more powerful and capable children, and greatly increases the chance of said children having magic;
4. If one accepts a dragon's heart, they will gain the ability to do magic (Ex: pyromancy for a fire dragon), or gain stronger magic if they have magic already (see, 1 out of 14 dragonslayers are mages);
5. It usually results in one having a dragon companion, which is useful for obvious reasons (transportation, powerful backup, and so much more)....

and of course, "hell hath no fury like a woman scorned" applies tenfold to dragons. After learning all this from their seers, the king would like to know **How Can A King Best Deal With Draconic Courtship Practices?**

Clarification:

1. The king is looking for the best way to handle this, as it appears that this will put dragonslayers in a position of power and therefore make them a threat to the system (AKA him and his noble supporters). He specifically wants a solution that he can implement that will:
   A. Ensure and maintain society's stability
   *and*
   B. Prevent dragonslayers from abusing this quirk of dragon culture to their benefit and his detriment; ie. balance this so they don't get overpowered.
2. If two half-dragons have a child, the result is a Dragonborn, a human who is both human *and* dragon and represents the full potential of each.
   Basically 1/2 + 1/2 = 1. Thus Dragonborn + half-dragon =1 1/2, half-dragon + human= 1 1/2. That's not to say the results are the same, however.

A Dragonborn & half-dragon pairing results in a Dragonborn that's a little more (specially 1/2 more) human, making them more spontaneous, adaptive, artistic, and intellectual than a regular Dragonborn.

A half-dragon and human pairing results in a human that has 1/2 dragon thrown into the mix, making them more passionate, aggressive, impulsive, and stubborn than a regular Dragonborn.

As always, I appreciate your input and feedback, so if you decide to VTC or downvote, please let me know why so I can improve this question. Thank you!

Comment: Newt Scamandar would be proud of you! I've just got to say, this idea is absolutely fascinating!

Comment: @elemtilas: out of curiosity, why? Also, nice to see (figuratively speaking) you again! FYI, I've made quite a few questions based off the Chomping Egg and Flailing Ooze questions you answered so well.

Comment: Are you kidding? Traditionally, dragonslayers just, well, kill dragons. Find the chink in the armour and thrust your sword right on in! You've just taken that to another level, by approaching the whole industry of dragonslaying by taking the behaviours of the prey and turning it around on them.  While I don't think Newt would be particularly fond of actually *slaying* any fantastic beasts, I do think he might praise your creativity in how you approach the natures of such beasts; and I do as well. This is orders of magnitude better than chomping eggs and flailing oozes!

Comment: @elemtilas: thank you, I'm rather proud of my recent worldbuilding successes. I hope to be getting some good answers for this soon.

Comment: You have a typo I don't know how to fix: "Accepting a dragon's advances comes with a lot of benefits and very few benefits;"

Comment: @Frostfyre: Thank you for pointing that typo out, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Dragons marrying humans and producing offspring isn't exactly new. Vietnamese, Chinese, Japanese, Slavic, and Armenian cultures all have stories of dragons marrying mortals and producing children, and in particular the royalty have used claims of draconic ancestry as a form of divine right.

Comment: Mmmmmm I do not like the implications of this question.

Answer (score 7):

If dragons can take human form then the problem already contains the solution: **Lizard Overlords**

The king and his nobles are themselves pure-blooded dragons. In the past a male dragon took on the guise of a human dragonslayer, found a suitable mate and with her help set up a new dynasty over the charred bones of the previous. Would-be dragonslayers now are mainly nominated by royal authority, and he only ever picks from the families of his fellow ruling dragons. After all, who best to overpower a dragon if not another dragon? Also, since dragons only want mates with sufficient power or skill, they can get rid of boring stuffy arranged marriages. The whole dragonslaying business would be how the dragons find a suitable match for their children. There may be some actual humans who try their luck without royal approval, but Sir Darwin will sort them out.

Thus, there is no conflict between dragon culture and that of the nobility, because they are the same thing. Societal stability is a nebulous thing, draconic rule can be done both overtly and covertly to that end. If your nobles are undeniably dragons, most rebellions can be nipped in the bud by the simple threat of dragonfire, thus maintaining peace and order. Otherwise, you can have a cabal of secret reptilian conspirators for maintaining the pretense of human rule.

Maybe you insist on having an actual pure-blooded human as king. A particularly martially inclined king could simply **pick up dragonslaying solely for himself**. The many benefits of picking up a dragon consort for a would be dragonslayer apply just the same to a king; even moreso, since the prestige acquired can be used to buffer his claim to the throne. Historical monarchies often justified their right to rule with the idea of a [divine mandate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_right_of_kings) so yours is simply a variation involving dragons. Also, if there's anyone you can expect to be loyal to you it's yourself.

Comment: This kind of touches on the broader problem with this question. Generally speaking, a world where sapient dragons that can breed with and empower humans are real *isn't* going to look like a standard medieval fantasy for the simple reason that feudalism and other medieval social constructs were solutions to the problems that existed at that time given available technology and demographics. A society with different resources and demographics will naturally come to different solutions, and won't look like feudal Western Europe unless the authors is forcing it.

Answer (score 4):

I see one problem here, from what I understand of your world: If Dragon A has been defeated by potential mate Dragon B, then while the defeated dragon A would be down for intercourse with B, B has no reason to mate with A, because B would want someone stronger than themself, which A has been proven to not be. And so on and so forth. If the "I want a stronger-than-me mate"-thing holds true to all dragons, that basically means all dragons would need to have mates from another species. Now, if "mate" includes "future parent of my offspring" the question is how the dragon species would propagate itself - IF you need two dragon parents to get a full-dragon child.

That problem would be solved if you needed only one parent of a full-dragon child to be a dragon as well (because something something magical mutation of human genes something).

This would potentially offer you one of the solutions you seek: Not everyone would be down with having your child be a whole different species than yourself.
I'm assuming that mate means something like lifelong sexual and romantic partner here.

Your king could do a few things, mostly simultaneously:

1. Not giving the dragon opportunity to court a Dragon Slayer or pull a "Hell Hath No Fury Like": No more orders for dragon-subduing, only for dragon-killing.
2. Only pair up male Dragon Slayers with male dragons, and female dragon slayers with female dragons: That's going to solve the problem of the heterosexual and heteroromantic dragons.
3. Only hire/train/send out married Slayers with children (has the downside of leaving more widowed spouses and orphans). Assuming cheating is culturally not accepted and being seen as morally wrong, and would if found out result in the cheater loosing their family (spouse and children) and reputation, then accepting a dragon's advances would be less tempting for a slayer. The king could codify some of these consequences in form of a law to be used in favour of the cheated-on spouse in court, for example.
4. Only send slayers out in groups. If defeating the dragon is a team effort, then no individual person is clearly stronger than the dragon, and no individual slayer will appear as an attractive mate to the dragon's eyes. Unless the dragon is down for polygamy.
5. Sterilisation or castration of some sort is also a possibility, but there would need to be massive benefits to becoming or staying a slayer to offset that large downside. Also, loosing your testicles means dropping natural testosterone levels and consequently muscle mass if I'm not mistaken, so the advantage male slayers would have over female slayers while training would largely disappear. Plus, introducing that would cost your king quite a few of his current slayers, who would not be down for loosing body parts to traditional castration methods.

Comment: These are all valid points, but I have to point out that dragons aren't completely insane (which can, hopefully, be inferred from the OP) and thus will not need to mate with other species. That being said, the best possible courtship outcome will probably be a tie, which means you are both equal.

Comment: @Alendyias Well, you DID explicitly say that "most dragons aren't sensible". You should probably change that up a little, since to be honest it kind of sounds like your dragon species should have gone extinct by now, since trying to find a mate sounds pretty life-threatening for them, if done outside of their own species - and right now that seems to be a common occurance.

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming dragonslayers are male, how to keep them from mating with
> impressed lady dragons they are trying to kill?

1. Gelding dragonslayer.  Might want to but can't.
2. Gay dragonslayer.  Not interested even if the lady is.
3. Child dragonslayer.  A couple of reasons no.

I think this would be a fine trio go out aslaying!

---

Three more: darker.

1. The monster.  He is beautiful, seductive and terrible.  He likes ladies but he likes them dead, or more than dead.  He should be put down, but instead is put to use.
2. The other monster: a lady dragon, hating her dragon form, trained to kill in her human form.  When she kills her own kind she symbolically kills the dragon that she is.
3. The paladin: he is the real thing, a rarity too pure to be seduced into relations with anyone but his wife.

These three would also be an excellent team, the paladin sent with the other two to watch them.  Each one hates the other two.

Comment: Given that historically, "children" as young as 14 might be, er, "settling down" already, well... let's just say I'm having a hard time imagining a ten-year-old having much luck defeating dragons. You may be onto something with the other two, though; +1.

Comment: The chance of there being a gelding or gay dragonslayer, at least in my mind, is very low. Historically, people were not kind to homosexuals, and what are the chances of someone ending up a gelding?

Comment: Oh; dragonslayers might be made eunuchs by order of the king. That's a dark turn I didn't expect....

Comment: @Matthew - anime is full of protagonists who appear to be 10 years old but who can somehow defeat ogres and monsters.  Much precedent in the world of fantasy for that.  Re the gay dragonslayer that character writes itself - he is a formidable fighter and wants to help people but is not welcome in the company of persons with similar skills because he is gay and he is too proud (with reason!) for the closet.  Re the gelding: accidents happen.  What are the chances of a warrior losing an eye, or a hand?

Comment: @Alendyias, I suspect that ("by order of the king") was the idea. Eunuchs were *more* common historically than now, and under the circumstances, it makes sense that that might be a (politically imposed) job requirement.

Comment: @Matthew Making gelding a job requirement wouldn't be unheard of either, historically certain cultures practiced precisely that

Comment: @Willk If dragons can live a long time they wouldn't see much difference between a ten year old human and a sixty year human and would easily be willing to practice spouse husbandry until a child dragonslayer comes of age. Just look at Lucoa and *Miss Kobayashi's Dragon Maid* for a good example of where that goes.

Comment: @user2352714 - if attraction is predicated on your potential mate actively and effectively trying to kill you it is hard to see how that can parlay into a long term relationship like spouse husbandry.

Comment: @Alendyias People are unkind to homosexuals because of whatever prevailing social norms are (also, look at places like Greece). If homosexuals are the only ones who can reliably defeat dragons, then their societal standing skyrockets. It's like the recent *Avatar* comics: it makes no sense for homophobia to be widespread when two of the last four Avatars (the most powerful people in the world and an international symbol of peace) were bisexual.

Comment: @Alendyias only in certain cultures,  the greeks for instance though gay men were manlier than straight men.

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1: PERSONAL DRAGON-HUNTER-HUNTERS**

The king could keep a loyal group of elite warriors paired up with an equally elite dragon, trained from the moment they fell for each other to be the ultimate anti-dragon and anti-dragon-slayer troops.

**OPTION 2: HOLY MATRIMONY BETWEEN KING AND DRAGON**

If you aren't afraid to drift into silly overtones, you can have some of the more egomaniacal kings become dragon-slayers themselves for the sole purpose of courting a dragon as a mate. I'm not referring to kings who assemble a group of warriors to professionally hunt them and take credit for the kills. I'm referring to kings who quite literally throw on some dragon-hunter gear and go out solo to fight and slay dragons.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your ideas, I appreciate new and creative perspectives!

Answer (score 1):

Initially this works out in the favor of both species.

Dragons get mates. Humans get power.

The problem comes from Interbreeding! The offspring of such a pairing will only inherit half the power that a dragon normally gets. Stronger than a human but much, much weaker than a pureblood dragon.

Undoubtedly, this will create a few factions and conflicts around "pure bloodedness" versus "freedom to choose" around dragon mating. It would eventually cause class stratification.

If a King wants to they could claim superiority over the person they sent to defeat the dragon thus being the "greater mate" for the dragon. With later interbreeding and pure blooded issues, the pure blood faction might set up political marriages to create agreements to not hunt pure blood dragons and dilute the bloodline while simultaneously boosting the power of the royal bloodline.

Comment: Congratulations, you prompted me to add more to the OP! Please see Point 2 under Clarification. Your answer was great, I just _really_ don't want a Mudblood-pureblood situation like the one in _Harry Potter_.

Comment: @Alendyias I don't mind. Even if it only helped you in improving the question, I am going to keep this here as a reference point as it might be useful to others!