# Balancing New Method of Enchantment Gain

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems

If you've seen my other questions on gaining Enchantments (like [Gaining The Engorgement Enchantment For Peasants](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/196989/gaining-the-engorgement-enchantment-for-peasants)) you know that [Enchantments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/201849/how-can-a-creature-with-focus-come-to-exist) can only be gained by the following methods:

1. Natural Weaponry-If one kills a monster with one's natural weaponry, one can gain a monster's Enchantment. Take Hercules strangling the Nemean Lion, for example. Under my Enchantment rules, that would get him the Lion's Enchantment, but not if he was wearing gloves. Why? Because if there is a 'buffer' between the body of the slayer and the monster being slayed, the buffer is what gets the Enchantment.
2. Integrative Weaponry-If one uses a weapon incorporating part of one's own body, like baby teeth or bones, to kill a monster both the weapon and the individual wielding it (*if* the wielder is the one who's body is incorporated into the weapon) will become Enchanted.
3. Eating-If one's digestive system is the weapon that kills a monster, one will gain the victim's Enchantment. However, this requires the monster to be eaten *alive*, which makes this difficult to do.

The trouble is, there is a magical principle involved here. When one is hunting or fighting a monster, a connection is forged between the two, and when that monster is killed, its magic naturally goes to that person by virtue of that connection. However, there is another way to gain magic, one that is less violent but in a way much harder to accomplish. A way that Kingdom Hearts would only approve of. *Love.*

Yes, I know. It might sound cheesy, but it forges a far stronger connection than the one described above. And when love is mutual, it causes a change within both involved, such that when a loved one is dead and gone, people still say they live on within. This is not the only way, however, because *magic is symbolic.*

Because there is something special about a first kiss (and by extension, true love's kiss), a human can gain part of another being's magic if they are his or her first kiss. **In clearer terms;** if a human Warrior's first kiss is a Siren, he will gain the power to A) swim as fast as a bottlenose dolphin (up to 36-54 km/h) and B) breathe underwater. This does not work if both people being kissed are not willing; they have to agree to do so.

Thus, humans can gain special power from Elves, Orcs, Goblins, Dwarves, Mermaids, Lamia, and Lizardmen (Reptorgs, I call them). Additionally, magic is shared when a magical being willingly marries a human being, turning the human into a magical being (Mage) themselves.

The trouble is **loopholes;** first and foremost, the trouble that this may serve to make one's first kiss and marriage more about magic than love. In other words, that the very thing that makes these things special may actually cheapen them as humans and other sentient beings make business arrangements based off this method of gaining Enchantments.

However, as much as I want to avoid this, if a first kiss works to grant someone magic, then I have to deal with the fact that a first kiss is not usually about love but is really more about hormones or curiosity, and its special effect is probably out of its milestone status (which makes it represent a step into another world in the above example). It only snowballs from there, because the principle that causes magic to be gained through marriage is that of *union,* and two people can be united without love. (It can certainly help, but it's not exactly necessary!)

And, as far as this applies to monsters, gaining a monster's loyalty can be as simple as feeding it regularly. **So my problem is, while I made Enchantments relatively difficult to gain, it appears this method of gaining Enchantments is a dangerous loophole.** How can I rectify that considering that this aspect of my magic system is based off of the principles of connection and union?

Please *note* that this is *very* necessary, as this question, [Dragonslayers: Accounting For Draconic Culture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197116/dragonslayers-accounting-for-draconic-culture), will tell you.

Comment: "Top speeds" of marine animals tend to be over-reported. This empirical study suggests top speeds of 28km/h are more likely for dolphins (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227624739_Maximum_swim_speeds_of_captive_and_free-ranging_delphinids_Critical_Analysis_of_extraordinary_performance).

Comment: I think the 54 km/h number is the speed at which bubble cavitation occurs. It's a theoretical speed limit. But that doesn't mean dolphins can actually reach the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer for the loophole issue is here:

> And when love is mutual, it causes a change within both involved, such that when a loved one is dead and gone, people still say they live on within. This is not the only way, however, because magic is symbolic.

> Because there is something special about a first kiss (and by extension, true love's kiss), a human can gain part of another being's magic if they are his or her first kiss. In clearer terms; if a human Warrior's first kiss is a Siren, he will gain the power to A) swim as fast as a bottlenose dolphin (up to 36-54 km/h) and B) breathe underwater. This does not work if both people being kissed are not willing; they have to agree to do so.

You mention that magic is symbolic, but many magic systems are also about *intent*. If the intent is weak or there is no intent, the magic is weak or there is no magic

1. You can pull a OUAT here and saying that the kiss that counts for Enchantment Gain is a **true love's kiss** and nothing else. A marriage of convenience / power wouldn't have any effect on Enchantment Gain, because they're not TRULY connected or united or bonded at the deepest level possible
2. You can have "tiers" of Enchantment gain, based on the degree of connection *between the beings involved*. A flimsy connection like a convenience / powerplay marriage that can be undone on a whim would result in a minor Enchantment Gain. So, if a human marries a Siren out of convenience, they wouldn't gain the ability to swim super fast and breathe underwater, they'll just swim slightly faster than average and hold their breath for longer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't consider there being 'tiers' of Enchantment gain, but I think it's genius!