# Gaining The Predatory or Gluttony Enchantment

Tags: low-fantasy

This can be considered an extension of [What Is the Most Efficient Way To Kill An Evolved Chomper?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197539/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-kill-an-evolved-chomper) and concerns gaining the Enchantments of a Glutton or Savage (ie. evolved Chomper).

In order to gain a monster's enchantment, there are only three ways of doing it:

1. Being inside the monster (but still alive) when it is killed: This is, obviously, dangerous to pull off. One cannot just hop in a monster's mouth, they have to be inside the stomach, have been at least a  little digested (y'know, the acid's done some damage to the skin, maybe even eaten through the first layer of skin, but nothing too serious), and as stated above, still be *alive* inside its stomach when it is killed in order to gain the monster's enchantment this way.
2. Killing it with natural weaponry: Even harder to pull off than 1, this involves you killing a monster as directly as possible. Hercules choking the Nemean Lion with his bare hands is a perfect example; had he done that in my world, with gloves on, the gloves would have been enchanted instead of him. You have to do it with your own body, and with skin contact, otherwise whatever's blocking the skin from connecting will be enchanted (gloves, boots, whatever).
3. I am the weapon: If you lose an arm in a farming accident, it could very well be an opportunity in disguise. You see, if you are the weapon, you gain the enchantment. Killing an evolved Chomper with a spear tipped with a sharp piece of your own bone will therefore get you Gluttony or Predatory. A sword made with bone steel, if the bones used to make it are your own, would do the same. However, Healers that can restore lost fingers, limbs, and the like are kind of rare (and are usually nobility), so this involves sacrifice.

So I have the general methods, but guess what? I accidentally made these things *almost unkillable.* (Seriously, please see [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197182/defending-medieval-villages-from-gluttons-and-savages), as it will help immensely in answering this question.) For in-story reasons, I'm not changing these things up, but that makes gaining enchantments from them kind of difficult. Thus, my question is **What Is The Most Efficient Way To Gain An Evolved Chomper's Enchantment?**

*Specifications:*

1. By "efficient," I mean most effective, the easiest to pull off, requiring the least amount of labor and resources to perform. This method (or methods, if you want to be thorough) should fit the criteria for method 1, 2, or 3; it should be a method of killing an evolved Chomper that will get the user the said monster's Enchantment.
2. Said methods should be **feasible for medieval Europeans**; something they can actually come up with and execute.

*Clarification:*

1. The enchantment gained from a Glutton is, quite rightly, named Gluttony. It enables the holder to absorb magic from any monster it injures or slays *directly*.

The enchantment gained from a Savage is called Predatory; any item or creature imbued with this enchantment wounds not just the physical aspect of an item or creature it hurts, but its very essence. This almost completely negates enhanced healing factors (think Wolverine) because that enhanced healing power has to go into restoring their wounded life force; in other words, Predatory cripples enhanced healing factors and is pretty dang lethal to boot.

2. While monster magic is released when a monster is killed, it only infuses (enchants) whatever killed it, whether that something was a person, a predator, a weapon, a boulder, or even old age. In the case of old age, the monster leaves behind its drops as normal but its magic is lost upon release, turning into pure (AKA plain) mana.
3. SirTain had a good question, one concerning what would happen if a club covered in an entire village's worth of baby teeth were to be used to kill a monster. The answer is not very fun; only the villagers whose teeth impact the monster will get any of its enchantment, and the amount of enchantment gained by any one villager will be directly proportional to how much damage their teeth did to said monster. The good news is, both the club and the villagers involved can steadily gain enchantments in this way.

Comment: I really like the idea of baby tooth clubs as listed by Willk below, and it made me think of a question for clarity.  Let's say you had a village embed the baby teeth of all their residents into a single club and then used that club to beat a monster to death.  Who/what gets the enchantment? Is it randomly one person?  Everyone?  Just the club?

Comment: @SirTain: great question! Please look at point 3 under Clarification for my answer.

Comment: forget bone you have hair, nails, and baby teeth you'll never miss.

Comment: @John: great point! However, any of those would likely be best added to iron to make steel, as using a steel sword to gain enchantments is by and large a much superior choice to a teeth-studded wooden club.

Comment: @Alendyias or just wrap hair around the wooden club.

Answer (score 4):

### Pit Traps

Pit traps have been an effective way to capture prey, including humans, for thousands of years.  Look up some of the traps used in the Vietnam War if you need better evidence.  We knew to look out for them, and we still lost a lot of people to them, so I think we can use them to catch things at Savage intelligence or below with moderate success.

After they're in the trap, you weaken them from a distance using weapons that you've enhanced by hunting these things (or other things) in the past.  Spears and rocks and the like.  If you don't have those, then you drop rocks on it and hit it with spears until it dies and now you have an enchanted weapon.

For the Glutton, I think your best bet is to <strike>suffocate it with your hands.</strike> drop bricks made out of hardened feces onto it:

1. Break its legs, crack its shell, make sure it spews all its acid as a defense mechanism and out of fear.  Wait for the acid to soak into the ground.
2. <strike>Wedge its mouth open with a combination of rocks, spears, poles, etc.</strike>
3. Climb down into the pit with it and bury your arms in its windpipe until it dies.  You can wear armor everywhere but your arms which need to do the actual strangulation bit.
4. Finish it off with bricks made with fecal matter.  Everyone who contributes to the killing brick will get a measure of the Glutton's power which will make harvesting monsters VASTLY easier since you can absorb monster powers just by contributing to the fight instead of having to deal the killing blow.
5. Profit.

*Note: Gluttons are a rookie monster hunter's first rodeo.  Odds are extremely high that veteran monster hunters use weapons created with brand new monster hunters' baby teeth and excretions in order to grant them the ability to grind powers easier.*

For the Savage, you first need a deeper hole because it's smarter.  You ABSOLUTELY also need the Glutton enhancement on everyone who's going after it because these things are big, scary, rare and you don't want to waste it.  Once it's in the hole, though, the solution is the same:

1. Drop rocks, hit it with enhanced weapons, punch it with your magic hands until it can't get out of the pit anymore.
2. Hit it more.  You need to break every one of its many limbs.
3. Dump water on it *(Edit: the water is actually buckets of urine so tat if it dies on accident you at least get the enhancement)* when it starts bleeding.  When water is added to a strong acid, it gets incredibly hot, this will possibly cauterize the bleeding, but also be very inconvenient for the creature that will be being burned alive even through its enamel shell.
4. <strike>Throw a bunch of dirt on it to soak up all the acid that it spews.</strike>
5. Have someone with the Glutton enhancement go down and choke it out.  It's got roughly human proportions, so you just have to get it in a chokehold and wait it out.  You'll probably need to hit it in the head with a hammer until the enamel around its neck starts to crack.
6. Wonder if maybe you should have just enhanced rocks and then used the enhanced rocks as weapons and armor.
7. When it looks very near death, finish it off with bricks just like the Glutton.  I cannot stress enough how deadly falling bricks can be, especially since there's a good chance any enhancements you have will be shared by your... bricks.

*Note: These plans do not have a 100% success rate and may result in permanent injury or death.  Do not try this at home.  Batteries not included.*

*Edit: Recent updates have caused me to want to change this plan slightly.*

Comment: Great answer! I now realize the need to add more information. I will add this (and explain more), but the Glutton enchantment won't help directly in killing a Savage.

Comment: I just edited and realized your answer is even better. You see, a Glutton's enchantment allows you to absorb the magic released when a monster is hurt or slain _just by being there_, and a Savage's enchantment allows you to wound a creature's very essence with your attacks, so the Glutton enchantment _would_ indeed help kill a Savage!

Comment: @Alendyias Inspired by Mike Serfas and Willk, I've made some changes to my plan.

Comment: Great job, I like how you've updated your plan to make it easier for more people to gain enchantments!

Answer (score 3):

### The Midden.

Think of it as a sort of pit trap.  But your castle already has *this* kind of pit.  The predatory gluttonous beastie has cleverly managed to infiltrate past the walls, which is undoubtedly a Very Bad Thing, but it was bound to happen.  Now what?

You can't kill it, but you can still beat at it with any weapon at hand.  You can perhaps drive it one way or another until it lands in a certain well trafficked room of the castle to which soldiers were frequently going and within which they often appear quite vulnerable to attack.

Once dropped into the Midden, perhaps you can cover it.  Perhaps you have a water source on hand to dump in.  Confined to this communal latrine, the Chomper may well decide this is the time to keep its big mouth *shut*.  But **[noxious vapors lurk down in there](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/africa/2850045.stm)**!  The beast weakens, struggles, tries to escape by taking a large gulp that sucks in everything nearby ... it Eats Midden and Dies, you might say.

No one knows which soldier in the camp will gain the enchantment - they all have a part of their body in the game - perhaps it is an incentive for them all to work together to make this happen.

Comment: I am so sorry, Mike Serfas, but I forgot to put in the OP the fact that the magic released upon a monster's death only enchants whatever killed it; in this case, the midden and its vapors. It's still a great answer though! "Savage, _eat midden!_"

Comment: You had that in the OP.  But you said a lost body part would give you the enchantment, and the material in the midden originated inside the body.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I didn't think of that! You're right, the midden tactic would get people the enchantment, just in diluted form; each enchantment gets weaker the more it ends up affecting. Still, since this is a safe and easily repeatable method, that's just a small setback.....

Answer (score 2):

1. **Poison**.  These things eat.  Watch what they eat.  Then provide that food doped with a lot of poison.  Plenty of poison.
   Hide and watch.
2. **Baby teeth**.  Everyone saves baby teeth!  You will affix them to a doughty club.  Each person has their own.  Now you are the weapon!  You and your baby teeth!
3. **Piñata !**   Did you see where everyone has their own baby tooth club?  That is for a good reason.  When the Glutton gets poisoned and is asleep or too sick to do much, a scaffold will be erected.  The people will get out their baby tooth clubs and gather round.  They hoist up the monster and then people take turns whaling away on it using their baby tooth clubs.  Lively music is played by a band.  When someone finally delivers the whack that pops the glutton, its enchantment pours out in a messy flood all over that person!  Blindfolds optional.

Comment: Great answer, very creative! I honestly did not think of overcoming a Savage or Glutton's defenses pinata-style, but it would be a very funny and effective (albeit brutal) way to do so. Baby-teeth clubs and weapons are also a very innovative idea!

Comment: I have a suggestion though; would it not be better to forge the baby teeth into steel and make a metal club, or perhaps a pick?

Comment: @Alendyias - I think the teeth will crack with the heat.  If you don't like the club, maybe a whip, with a single tooth at the tip.  Whip Pinata would be exciting now that I think of it.

Comment: Willk, teeth can and do disintegrate when exposed to high heat, but adding enough of that dust to iron should make some very nice steel, capable of getting you a very nice enchantment.