# Usefulness of Pyris Enchantment

Tags: magic, items

Have you ever looked at something and went "Cool bro, but where's the fire?" or perhaps even "BRING ME FIAH!" Well, the magical forces in Alendyias did just that.

At that very moment, a Quad (a four-legged [Chomper](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/199981/making-a-predator-for-chompers)) mutated, both of its jaws bifurcating until it had a four-part beak. This beak opened, and a stream of flame rushed out, setting an unfortunate Leafmaw (a sort of giant worm that looks like a pile of leaves and eats stupid kids who try to jump in it) ablaze. A new monster had been born; a Torchblow.

After Torchblows entered the picture, someone had the bright idea to crush it using the village catapult, dropping a stone brick on it. To their surprise, when they found the brick, it had a red-orange hue, as if lit by firelight, and it burned to the touch, just like a real flame. They had discovered the Pyris enchantment.

This odd enchantment imbues something with the glow and heat of a typical flame (think torch, not bonfire), making it fireproof in the process. However, it is somewhat specific in what it affects. Organic objects, like wood and bone, steel, or stone (specifically fossils, limestone, and any other stone that contains either calcium or carbon) alone can gain Pyris. If it's an organic object, it must be hard, or at least stiff; soft organics like wool or fabric turn to ash when hit by this Enchantment, and then become a significant fire hazard. Liquids or gels of organic origin, however, can gain Pyris.

Also, water does not extinguish the inner flame granted by Pyris, it only weakens it. A brick with Pyris would be comfortably warm underwater, being cooled by the water around it, but if it was frozen....no more Pyris. Generally, though, this is useless information, as one would have to drop a Pyris object into the Arctic Sea for the water to be cold enough to extinguish its flame.

So, my question is **How Useful Is The Pyris Enchantment?**

**Specifications For Best Answer:**

1. The best answer will list all the objects that could gain *and* would benefit from the Pyris enchantment. Keep in mind, in order to gain the Pyris enchantment, an object must both fulfill the above criteria and be capable of killing a Torchblow (because killing a Torchblow with an object is how you give it the Pyris enchantment).
2. The best answer will also explain where, why, and how objects with the Pyris Enchantment would be useful. A good example would be stone walls to keep Plops away from the village's crops since Pyris bricks would repel the smart ones and burn up the dumb and/or stubborn ones on contact.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have invented heating units.

Constantly producing heat, Pyris imbued objects would prove really useful:

- do you want to take a bath? Drop a Pyris brick in the bathtub and enjoy
- do you need to travel in January? A Pyris brick in the chariot or in the room will raise the temperature to a more comfortable level
- do you need to cook but no wood is at hand? Use a Pyris block to heat up a base, and you will be able to cook/grill everywhere
- do you want a fancy house? A large Pyris rock in the basement will help you providing warm water and warm air to every single room, instead of having to light a fireplace in each of them

Comment: Oh my goodness, I _have_ invented heating units! HOW did I not see that?!

Comment: Use for cooking and heating, without the constant need to grow or gather wood, would revolutionize medieval life.

Comment: If you use a large enough boulder in the catapult, you can then break the heat boulder into hundreds of pieces and supply an entire village from a single Torchblow.

Answer (score 2):

There is the capability of infinite candle light as the flame makes the material magically fireproof and extremely flammable, essentially, if you take away the melting of a candle and the wick, the candle will burn forever for as long as there is oxygen. This enchantment could also be used in an industrial setting if it can serve as a post forging fireproof setting and furnace, such as making an intensely heat resistant boiler that always maintains a constant high heat as the liquid inside will continue to heat up more and more the longer it stays inside the container until it reaches boiling point. There may need to be an outer shell to contain the heat and to allow oxygen to flow around the boiler for the flame to kick in. As for killing the torchblows, dropping a mass of solid organic wax on them and containing the wax inside a lantern-like container. simply dropping materials onto a restrained torchblow would suffice for killing them. Then to make the boiler, just drop a steel container filled with solid clay(which can't gain the enchantment, thus allowing the enchantment to solely apply to the steel. Then, dropping the filled container onto the torchblow would allow for the inner shell of the boiler to be made after picking it up indirectly and then emptying the container of the clay.