# How Dangerous Are Evolved Ploppers?

Tags: mythical-creatures, medieval

This is the sequel to [How Dangerous Are Ploppers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/199706/how-dangerous-are-ploppers)
and covers one vital aspect of Ploppers: **evolution.**

Sure, Ploppers aren't much of a threat, but they grow up, evolving into a stronger equivalent of a Glutton or Savage: a Glopper or Savager. As stated succinctly in [What Is the Most Efficient Way To Kill An Evolved Chomper?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197539/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-kill-an-evolved-chomper), killing either a Glutton or a Savage is pretty difficult.

At this point, you may be wondering: **Just How Would One Determine The Capabilities Of An Evolved Plopper?** A Glutton's chitin is 7x tougher than a regular Chomper's shell (which is as hard as tooth enamel), and a Savage's armor is twice as hard as a Glutton's chitin (14x tougher than tooth enamel), so a Glopper's chitin would be 7x tougher than a Plopper's and a Savager's would be 14x tougher.

As for intelligence, a Glopper would be twice as intelligent as a Glutton and a Savager would be twice as intelligent as a Savage. Speed, a Plopper is 3x as faster as a Chomper, and in my estimation, since a Glutton is around the same size range as a buffalo or hippo, a Glopper would still be limited to at least 30 mph, while a Savager would be much faster, in the 60-70 mph range.

In my estimation, a Glopper should be capable of surviving: a boulder being dropped on them, a car crashing into them, being dropped from seven stories up, and thanks to their decentralized nervous system and gel-packed organs, they are almost impossible to take down with concussive damage. That being said, just like a Plopper, Gloppers are vulnerable to sustained or extremely hot flame, and become brittle when frozen.

Savagers? Oh, they're *twice as tough* as a Glopper. As for as offense go, both are *much* more dangerous than a Plopper. Gloppers have six wheel-tipped legs and a huge maw with a eight-foot-long, prehensile tongue and four tentacles behind the jaws to aid in feeding, not to mention acid capable of eating through even cobblestone in mere seconds, which they can fire either in bursts that spray out over a 3x3 area or a stream that eats through an area of 2 square feet where it lands.

Savagers have two wheel-tipped legs and four reptilian arms, which can extend up to six feet and end in razor-sharp talons capable of opening doors and wielding weapons skillfully. Their tails can also extend six feet and end in a razor-sharp, diamond-shaped spiked maul.  Their jaws can split steel beams in two with ease, not to mention fire 4x4 streams of caustic fluid, capable of corroding metal. Their bodily fluids are just as corrosive.

In conclusion, my question is **How Dangerous Are Evolved Ploppers?**

**Specifications For Best Answer:**

1. The best answer will analyze the lethality of a Glopper and Savager (its ability to harm or kill medieval Europeans) and its CRD (Capacity to Resist Dying) to determine how dangerous it is. CRD is based off a monster's durability, and how hard it would be for medieval Europeans with medieval weaponry to kill or harm that monster.
2. The best answer will also take the Rarity of Ploppers into account, which have a 1/4 chance of evolution; out of 100 Ploppers, only a fourth of them will manage to evolve into a Glopper (25 Gloppers). Out of those 100, only one-sixteenth will evolve into a Savager, which ends up as 6 Savagers. Plops and Chompers have populations akin to that of rats in the wild, and 90% of Chompers who eat a Plop transform into a Plopper, which means there is a fair number of Ploppers, a number open to interpretation.

Comment: Evolution doesn't work this way. Ploppers may grow into something else, but individual Ploppers will not evolve into anything.

Comment: @NomadMaker I'm pretty sure that in here the term evolution is being used in a  loose fantasy sense much like we see in how it's used with Pokemon and Digimon (probably more Pokemon in here though, since the plopper's "evolution" doesn't get mingun arms) rather than its actual meaning as a biological process.