# Utility of Giant Axe

Tags: science-based, items

Okay, so we have a guy with an oversized axe. The handle is basically a log, the blade that of a battleaxe but the size of a big-screen TV. To be more specific, the blade is big (wide/long) enough that it *could* cleave a tree trunk in two with a single blow. The 'axe dude' is strong enough that he can use the axe for this exact purpose, felling a tree with a single blow.

Thus we have Axe and Lumberjack. The Lumberjack can wield the battleaxe like a regular axe, despite its increased weight and size, and the axe is self-sharpening (is always razor-sharp, AKA the edge won't dull, blunt, or roll). In essence, we have a Really Good Blade (important for the question) and a typical physics-bending brute (a mere archetype).

My question is, **In the Hands of Someone Strong Enough To Use It Properly, How Dangerous Would Such An Axe Be?** In other words, with a super-strong man to use it, how dangerous would a giant axe with a remarkable edge be? Keep in mind, this axe can slice right through a tree with one blow....

*Clarification:*

1. The best answer will take into account what a giant axe would be used *for* (felling trees, chopping wood and/or stones, destroying an enemy knight, defeating a [Savage](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197182/defending-medieval-villages-from-gluttons-and-savages))
2. Please assume that the ax user can wield the ax effectively despite its disproportionate weight and length.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: thanks for the edit, I didn't realize I had spelled axe wrong!

Comment: only if the super strong wielder is also huge, when you swing an axe the axe swings you. If the axes weight is not close to the same proportional weight of a normal axe to a normal person it can't be wielded effectively.

Comment: 'Ax' and 'axe' are both correct spellings. Axe is more common, though. See, for example, [Merriam-Webster Dictionary article on this topic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/ax-vs-axe-difference). I believe 'ax' once was preferred US spelling while 'axe' was used almost universally in British English. Today, 'axe' seems to be the preferred version in both US and Br English.

Comment: @John: please assume that the user can use the ax effectively despite that aspect of physics.

Comment: If need to cover dragons and other mythical creatures in our answers then it becomes an open ended speculation. Can you be more specific about what this axe should be used against?

Comment: @Alendyias then what's the question it sounds like you just want brainstorming which is way off topic.

Comment: So, we have a handle the size of a "log" (undefined length and mass) and a blade the size of a "big-screen TV" big enough to cleave a tree trunk (undefined dimensions and mass) being wielded by a "strong" person who can ignore the laws of physics (meaning undefined wielding speed) against an unspecified opponent.  Without defining any variables a science-based answer isn't possible.

Comment: I've no preference as to the spelling, it's distracting when there are alternate spellings every other line or sometimes in the same sentence (as per after the edit, hint, hint OP). @Otkin

Comment: If the answer to this question should be science-based, the only science an answer could refer to is history science. It would depend on the level of civilization and technology your world has reached. Would "close combat" be relevant ? and if yes, is that Bronze age, Classic age, Roman age, medieval ? What other weapons are available.. At some point in time,  say late Bronze age, the battle axe appeared, then it disappeared. Now suppose you'd *upscale* the weapon, would that have prevented the battle axe to disappear in medieval times ?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I agree that alternate spellings in the same text are annoying (unless they serve a specific purpose). However, the original had 11 'ax' and 2 'axe'. You changed all 'ax' to 'axe'.  Wouldn't it make more sense to change 'axe' to 'ax' instead?

Comment: I think it is very hard to quantify 'dangerous'. I disagree that the question is 'opinion-based', but I do think that it needs clarifications. Please define 'dangerous' or replace it with something that is quantifiable to fit the WB.SE guidelines.

Comment: @Otkin Easier for me yes, you might suppose. The darned rules of editing prohibit anything below a threshold (I forget) which makes the niggling edit impossible. Sweeping change happens, else none, or a little change and addition of spurious edits to make-up the quota. I'd rather tweak, but the machine regards the tiny as trivial and blocks it.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 In point of fact, the lumberjack is said to be only "psychics-bending," not physics-bending.  Like in Avatar, this means he can telekinetically control psychics.  He has to find them first, though.  A lot of people claim to be psychic but how many are real?  However, arguably, the lumberjack is a psychic himself and he could target himself with psychic-bending, which would let him fly and be very dangerous indeed.

Comment: This is a science-based question. Please ignore all laws of physics and logic, and answer in a precise science-based way....... ha. Yeah, I'll pass. That's like putting both "magic" and "hard-science" tags on the same question

Comment: Ah, a Paul Bunyan question!  You might consider axing this over on [Mythology & Folklore](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions). Axing how dangerous an ax would be if your Ol Paul character wielded the axe is axing for tall story based opinions of gargantuan, nay of pantegruelian proportions!

Answer (score 1):

**How dangerous are close quarters?**

The less dangerous it is to close with your enemy, the better your big dude with sharp axe will be.  He can scythe his way thru an army of scrawny dudes.  He can put down a big monster or another big dude (reminder: you should aim for the head) with one hit.  If that is the kind of fight you have, he is a lumberjack and he's OK!

But there are things you should not close with.  A pack of many zombies only needs one bite and odds favor them.  Cheetu is much faster than Axecop; Cheetu will not get hit and will dart in, open an artery and then back away and watch. Giggling. Something with a ranged attack will hit Lumberjack, and hit many times before your guy can get in hacking range, if he ever does.  Something like a hydra or a black pudding that is not much fazed by getting cut will be bad news.

Context is everything!